# MySQL disconnect from server for new "prepare"

Tags: mysql, perl

I'm working on a Perl script which executes few queries on SQL server.

For example:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare   (  "select x y z ..   );
$sth->execute();

# do some code

my $sth = $dbh->prepare   (  "select a b c ..   );
$sth->execute();

# do some code

# etc..
```

It is recommended to disconnect from the server explicitly `$dbh->disconnect`. 
Do I need to disconnect after each execution ? Or it is enough to disconnect only once when script is finished ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**, you do not need to disconnect every time. That would be very contra-productive.

You can just fire as many queries as you want. But take into account that you are redeclaring `$sth` if you use `my` every time.

---

Typically if there are several tables that you need to fill, it would look something like this.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;

my $dsn = '...';
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn);

my $sth_employee = 
  $dbh->prepare('select name, title, department_id from employee');
my $sth_department = 
  $dbh->prepare('select name from department where department_id=?');

$sth_employee->execute;
while (my $res_employee = $sth_employee->fetchrow_hashref) {
  $sth_department->execute($res_employee->{department_id});
  ( my $department ) = $sth_department->fetchrow_array;
  say $res_employee->{name};
  say "$res_employee->{title}, $department";
  say '=' x 10;
}

# no need to explicitly finnish handles or disconnect, DBI does that for us
```

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#disconnect):

> Disconnects the database from the database handle. disconnect is typically only used before exiting the program. The handle is of little use after disconnecting.

So no.

Disconnecting just means you have to reconnect. It would be a waste of resources.